# How to solve one equation for two unknowns

Tags: calculus, nonlinear-system

I have an equation with two unknowns:

$$y = {25 \over (x-0.5)^2 } + {10 x}.$$

Is it possible to solve such an equation, I read somewhere that I can use differentiation but I'm not sure how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting the result equal to zero or some constant?

Comment: Well, this is basically a function. Maybe you are making something up here. What is the original task? When you have just one equation you can not solve it when you have two unknows. You need two equations for that.

Comment: You can "solve" this equation, but the set of solutions is best described via a graph...

Comment: @Cornman actually y is a total cost and x is a service-time rate. Basically, I'm trying to find x that minimizes the total cost by plotting x versus y. So I thought maybe I should solve this equation to do so.

Comment: @XanderHenderson how can I do so?

Comment: Oh use differentiation to do it. The derivative should be very easily solvable.

Comment: If you're looking to find x that minimizes y, then that's not exactly the same as solving for the equation.  (Solving for an equation means finding the function that satisfies it, which in this case would be trivial since the function is given.)  You are correct in that finding this involves differentiation.  What you want to do is find $y'$ and then determine the values of $x$ that set $y'$ equal to zero.  This will be when the slope is zero, meaning that at that point, the value of the function may be at its lowest or highest.  In short, find $x$ such that $y'=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're trying to find:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left\{\frac{\text{n}_1}{\left(x-\text{n}_2\right)^2}-\text{n}_3\cdot x\right\}=-\frac{2\cdot\text{n}_1}{\left(\text{n}_2-x\right)^3}-\text{n}_3=0\tag1$$

Now, we get one real solution:

$$x=\text{n}_2-\left(\frac{2\cdot\text{n}_1}{\text{n}_3}\right)^\frac{1}{3}\tag2$$

So:

$$\text{y}\left(\text{n}_2-\left(\frac{2\cdot\text{n}_1}{\text{n}_3}\right)^\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{3}{2^\frac{2}{3}}\cdot\text{n}_1^\frac{1}{3}\cdot\text{n}_3^\frac{2}{3}-\text{n}_2\cdot\text{n}_3\tag3$$

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. Though I think there is a negative sign missing before  $$ {2*n_1 \over (n_2-x)^3 } .$$

Comment: @DML2014 You're right, I edited my answer!